# Smooth approximation of $f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if}\;x<0\\x&\text{if}\;x \geq 0 \end{cases}$

Tags: functions, derivatives, approximation, smooth-functions

I'd like to find a smooth function to approximate $$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if}\;x<0\\x&\text{if}\;x \geq 0 \end{cases}$$
 This function should be differentiable everywhere. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "smooth"?  This term is generally used to mean something like "having as many derivatives as required by the context," so you have to tell us what your context is.

Comment: I mean it should be differentiable everywhere. Just for the first order derivative, not necessary to be infinitely differentiable.

Answer (score 2):

This is the ReLu function. You can approximate it with the softplus function which is given by

$$ f_{t} = \frac{1}{t} \ln(1+e^{tx}) $$

As $\lim_{t \to \infty} f_{t}  = f(x) $

Here is some visualization with Python

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def relu(array):
    y = list(map(lambda x: max(0,x), array))

    return y

def softplus(array, t):

    f_t = (1/t)*np.log(1+np.exp(array*t))
    return f_t

my_range = np.arange(start=-100, stop=100, step=0.5)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
r = relu(my_range)
f_t_01 = softplus(my_range, 0.01);
f_t_1 = softplus(my_range, 0.1)
f_t_5 = softplus(my_range,0.5)
ax.plot(my_range, r, label='Relu')
ax.plot(my_range, f_t_01, label='Softplus - 0.01')
ax.plot(my_range, f_t_1, label = 'Softplus - 0.1')
ax.plot(my_range, f_t_5, label = 'Softplus - 0.5')
plt.title('Comparison')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.quora.com/What-smooth-approximations-to-the-ReLu-function-are-available-in-TensorFlow, an approximation is $\frac{1}{t}$ln$(1+e^{tx})$. Here $t$ is a positive number - the larger $t$ is, the more accurate the approximation will be. As $x$ approaches $\pm\infty$, the function will be more accurate. It is most inaccurate at $x=0$, with an error of ln$(2)/t$.

Comment: Thanks! I have seen that one. My concern is that to get the error down at `x=0` `t` has to be large, but then with not so large `x` elsewhere the `exp(tx)` part will explode numerically quickly...

Comment: At $x=0$ we have that $f_{t} = \frac{1}{t} \ln(1+1)= \frac{\ln(2)}{t} $ then consider that $ \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{\ln(2)}{t} = 0$ ...even with $t=2$ the error is $\frac{ln(2)}{2} \approx .34  $ ...$t = 10$, we have $\approx 0.07$

Comment: With what range of $x$ are you working with @JianghuiDu?

Comment: from `10^{-8}` to `10^3`